# Only change one item in List using ForEach SwiftUI Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a view in a loop using ForEeach to show a list in an array using Core Data relationships.

The View is showing all of the elements in each loop and I need to segment them out individually while being able to keep toggling the button and it not toggle all of the goals at the same time.

Edit: I figured out how to make it so they all weren't iterating and showing but now toggling any of the buttons toggles them all. :(

GameGoalDetail

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct GameGoalsDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Game.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var games: FetchedResults<Game>

    @State private var showingAddGoal = false

    @State private var goalComplete : Bool = false

    @ObservedObject var game: Game

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.game.gameName ?? "No Game Name").font(.title)
            Text(self.game.gameDescription ?? "No Game Description").font(.subheadline)
            List {GameGoalListView(game: self.game).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
                }
            Button("Add Game Goal") {
                self.showingAddGoal.toggle()
            }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddGoal) {
                    AddGameGoalsView(game: self.game).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameGoalsListView

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct GameGoalListView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Game.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var games: FetchedResults<Game>

    @ObservedObject var game: Game

    @State private var goalComplete : Bool = false


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(game.goalArray, id: \.self) { goal in
                HStack {
                    Text(goal.goalName ?? "No Goal Name")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Complete:").font(.caption)
                    Image(systemName: self.goalComplete ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "app").onTapGesture {
                        self.goalComplete.toggle()
                        print(self.goalComplete)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what is happening:
[image: Screenshot of all items being toggled]

After clicking:
[image: All items toggled instead of one]

I'm trying to have it so that when a goal is added, it shows in the List and then I can select if the goal is completed or not via the button.
So each Game would have a list of different goals that are added by user input.

Would really appreciate help & can provide further info as requested.

Comment: You need to add a lot more context. It's hard to understand what you're even asking here, not to mention what you're code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Pierce I added some more context. Would seeing the Core Data classes help?

Comment: Now I kind of understand what you're trying to do, but I don't necessarily understand the problem you're encountering while trying to do it. I don't know if showing your CD classes would really help, my intuition says that it's not important, it sounds like you're maybe having an issue with your logic or how your UI is set up?

Comment: You are iterating the goal list in both the outer and inner views.   Don’t you want just one of these loops?  Can you show what the output should look like?

Comment: @Paulw11 I edited it so that only the inner view iterates but now all of the items are being toggled instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to rework so much of this but with the help from a fantastic Redditor, I got it figured out.

GameGoalsDetail

- I didn't need the Fetch Request because it was being passed in from the view.
- Didn't need the @State because I should've been using the CoreData info directly.

```
List {
    ForEach(game.goalArray, id: \.self) { goal in
        GameGoalListView(goal: goal)
    }
}
```

Only needed the GameGoalListView(goal: goal) passed in because I redid the GameGoalListView.

GameGoalListView

- Got rid of the @State again and the @FetchRequest
- The List in GameGoalsDetail is what is showing each goal, so an additional ForEach isn't needed in this view. This view just needed to show the thing that needed to be shown and the information pulled from CoreData.

The @ObservedObject is the Goal not the Game.
The onTapGesture is accessing the goal.goalComplete from CoreData and not the State (which creates a new Source of Truth (watch the WDCC video)).

Then the onReceive and objectWillChange let the goal knows it's changing every time the button is tapped.

```
struct GameGoalListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @ObservedObject var goal: Goal
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(goal.goalName ?? "No Goal Name")
                Spacer()
                Text("Complete:").font(.caption)
                Image(systemName: self.goal.goalComplete ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "app").onTapGesture {
                    self.goal.goalComplete.toggle()
                    print(self.goal.goalComplete)
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(self.goal.objectWillChange) {
            try? self.moc.save()
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, the help came from a Redditor and I hope this helps someone figure out what I was messing up and fix their error.

Comment: Thx, this is exactly what I was looking for. Good solution!

Comment: for id: `\.self` can you substitute `\.objectID`?